# Big database optimisation

Tags: php, mysql, database

I created a web service that generates **huge requests every seconds**.
Sometimes the MYSQL service seem **down few secondes** and work again well.

The main table contain more than `4 420 115 entries` since one month.

Storage engine : InnoDB

The server configuation :

```
CPU : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU D-1540 @ 2.00GHz
Coeurs : 16
Cache : 12288KB
RAM : 4x 32Go
Disques : 2 x 480 Go
```

The my.cnf :

```
skip-external-locking
key_buffer      = 16M
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
query_cache_limit   = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M
```

Can I have advices to avoid this problem and increase the mysql performances.
Thank's

Comment: Which storage engine you are using. show your query and the explain of it. There can be many reason

Comment: There are several things to work. First at all make sure you my.cnf configuration is correct. After that, activate a mysql-slow log where you can find the slow queries that might be bloking your tables which seems to be what happen here. After you have all the info you can start work ahead in query performance in order to fix it.

Comment: I just active the Slow Query. How can i be sure my my.cnf configuration is correct ? I never changed it.

Answer (score -2):

Sounds like it may be time to iterate on the database structure and application logic to reduce the amount of DB interactions. Another option is adding a memcached or redis layer between the application and the SQL database to provide near millisecond response time for read actions.